# Automatically set the primary key for one table as the foreign key for another?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

**I have two Django models:**

```
class seller_event(models.Model):
    event_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 300, default = 'Null')
    description = models.CharField(max_length = 300, default = 'Null')
    location = models.CharField(max_length= 300, default = 'Null')
    cash_payment = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    paytm_payment = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.event_id)

class seller_event_items(models.Model):
    item_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    event_id = models.ForeignKey(seller_event)
    item_name = models.CharField(max_length = 300, default = 'Null')
    item_price = models.CharField(max_length = 300, default = 'Null')
    item_quant = models.CharField(max_length = 300, default = 'Null')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.item_id)
```

The foreign key for the second table is the primary key for the first table. Essentially, I am trying to associate items with a sale. I have a forms like such:

**forms.py:**

```
class Seller_event(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = seller_event
        exclude = {'user'}

class Seller_event_items(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = seller_event_items
        exclude = {'event_id'}
```

**views.py:**

```
def newlist(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        user = request.user
        print user
        if request.method == 'POST':
            seller_event_form = Seller_event(request.POST)
            seller_event_items_form = Seller_event_items(request.POST)
            if seller_event_form.is_valid() and seller_event_items_form.is_valid():
                new_seller_event = seller_event_form.save(commit=False)
                new_seller_event.user = user
                new_seller_event.save()
                seller_event_items_form.save()
                return redirect('/home')

        else:
            seller_event_form = Seller_event()
            seller_event_items_form = Seller_event_items()


        return render(request, 'home/newlist.html', {'seller_event_form': seller_event_form, 'seller_event_items_form': seller_event_items_form})
```

The form here is helping a seller both create a sale and then populate the sale with items.

How can I go about automatically setting the fk on the items table as the event_id (pk for seller_events table)? I have excluded it from the form, but I'm not sure what to do after this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do it in exactly the same way you are already setting the user on the new_seller_event.

The relationship between the event and the user is the same as the relationship between the item and the event.

Answer (score 3):

add this line before `seller_event_items_form.save()` when the model is saved 
you can reference it as ForeignKey

```
seller_event_items.event_id = new_seller_event
```